# FTP from command line not working?

Tags: windows, ftp

I am running an [FTP server](http://www.warftp.org/) on my PC. I opened Windows Explorer and navigated to: `ftp://127.0.0.1/`. I connect and the servers root directory files are displayed, great.

However, from a cmd prompt I am unable to successfully ftp into the server:

```
C:\>ftp ftp.localhost
Unknown host ftp.localhost.
ftp> bye

C:\>ftp ftp://localhost
Unknown host ftp://localhost.
ftp> bye

C:\>ftp ftp://127.0.0.1
Unknown host ftp://127.0.0.1.
ftp>
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Should I delete this question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try ftp localhost (without the ftp://)

```
ftp localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER: `"C:\>ftp localhost"`